# Scraping data from strange dashboard format

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

I'm working on aggregating COVID vaccination data, and I'm trying to use Python to scrape the vaccine numbers off this site (the first one -- "People who received 1 dose"). I'm trying to use BeautifulSoup to extract the HTML and then search by XPath or Attribute. First, of course, I parse the page using BeautifulSoup:

```
rhode_island = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://ri-department-of-health-covid-19-data-rihealth.hub.arcgis.com').content, 'html.parser')
```

But this HTML output looks nothing like the actual HTML on the page -- instead, it's just line after line of something like this:

```
%22%5D%7D%2C%22validationClasses%22%3A%7B%22fieldSuccess%22%3A%5B%22field-success%22%5D%2C%22fieldError%22%3A%5B%22field-error%22%5D%2C%22controlSuccess%22%3A%5B%22control-success%22%5D%2C%
```

I'm not exactly sure what's happening here -- I've tried a few different methods (LXML, Beautiful Soup) but both return this weird result. As a result, I can't scrape out the info I'm looking for because it's not really the HTML, it seems (I've tried and the scrape fails).

Anyone have any idea what I might be able to do to scrape this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page is Javascript heavy, needs a browser to have the data properly rendered, and is using ArcGIS REST API under the hood.

Either load the page in a browser with something like [`selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/), or look into where they are getting the data from - in this case, it seems, it is a `COVID_Public_Map_TEST` dataset which you could query:

```
In [1]: import requests

In [2]: session = requests.Session()

In [3]: session.headers = {'Accept': '*/*', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

In [4] response = session.get('https://services1.arcgis.com/dkWT1XL4nglP5MLP/arcgis/rest/services/COVID_Public_Map_TEST/FeatureServer/2/query', params={'f': 'json', 'where': '1=1', 'returnGeometry': 'false', 'outFields': '*'})

In [5]: data = response.json()  

In [5]: data
Out[5]: 
{'objectIdFieldName': 'OBJECTID',
 'uniqueIdField': {'name': 'OBJECTID', 'isSystemMaintained': True},
 'globalIdFieldName': '',
 'fields': [{'name': 'OBJECTID',
   'type': 'esriFieldTypeOID',
   'alias': 'OBJECTID',
...
    'New_Covid_Fatality_Today': 23}},
  {'attributes': {'OBJECTID': 40,
    'City_Town': 'WOONSOCKET',
    'Count_of_COVID_19_Positive': 27,
    'Rate_per_1k': 0.00027,
    'Population_per': 99999,
    'Date': 1586304000000,
    'Covid_case': 77812,
    'Covid_Deaths': 1625,
    'Covid_Positive_Today': 395,
    'Total_Hospitalized': 459,
    'Covid_ICU': 56,
    'Covid_Ventilator': 29,
    'Total_Covid_Lab_Tests': 1817360,
    'Negative_Covid_Lab_Tests': 1723464,
    'New_Covid_Fatality_Today': 23}}]}
```

You could do aggregations via the `outStatistics` query parameter.

Or, even better, look into how you could use Python ArcGIS API to do the same in a more convenient way.